# vb.net adding and removing controls to panel memory usage

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Good afternoon all,
I am writing an application that is used in our company. On one of the main forms, there are a 3 panels, each having custom user controls added and removed.  However, each time the timer runs and either adds/removes a control, the memory usage for the application climbs and never does go back down.  If i add a few controls and leave them there, the memory usages will eventually climb to 1.4GB, and the application will crash.  Here is the code that runs in a timer.  I am obviously doing something really wrong and would appreciate any assistance that could be provided.

```
    Private Sub tmrCoreCalls_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrCoreCalls.Tick
    Dim newCoreCalls As New ArrayList
    tmrCoreCalls.Enabled = False
    Dim a As New SqlDataProvider.SqlDatabase("Data Source=" & getDatabaseServer() & ";Initial Catalog=Application;User ID=XXXX;Password=XXXX")
    Dim myreader As IDataReader = a.ExecuteReader("vault.dbo.CallControl_getcorequeuedcalls", CommandType.StoredProcedure)
    Dim tmp, tmp2 As objCoreCall
    While myreader.Read
        tmp = New objCoreCall
        tmp.CallID = myreader("callid").ToString
        tmp.Ani = myreader("ani").ToString
        tmp.Line = myreader("line").ToString
        tmp.Queue = myreader("queue").ToString
        tmp.Wait = myreader("wait").ToString
        tmp.Channel = myreader("channel").ToString
        tmp.DNIS = myreader("dnis").ToString
        tmp.CallType = "CORE"
        If InStr(UCase(tmp.Queue), "PARK") Then
            tmp.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Coral
        End If
        newCoreCalls.Add(tmp)
        tmp = Nothing
    End While
    If qcalls.Controls.Count = 0 Then
        For Each tmp In newCoreCalls
            qcalls.Controls.Add(tmp)
            If InStr(UCase(tmp.Queue), "PARK") Then
            Else
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Insert from 0 records: " & tmp.Queue)
                My.Computer.Audio.Play(Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath & "\priCall.wav", AudioPlayMode.Background)
            End If
        Next
        myreader.Close()
        tmrCoreCalls.Enabled = True
        newCoreCalls = Nothing
        a = Nothing
        myreader = Nothing
        tmp2 = Nothing
        tmp = Nothing

        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim i As Integer
    'Remove all dead ones

    Dim isfound As Boolean = False
    For Each tmp3 As objCoreCall In qcalls.Controls
        For Each tmp In newCoreCalls
            If tmp.CallID = tmp3.CallID Then
                isfound = True
                tmp3.Wait = tmp.Wait
            End If
        Next
        If isfound = False Then
            'qcalls.Controls(i).Dispose()

            qcalls.Controls.Remove(tmp3)
            tmp3.Dispose()
            tmp3 = Nothing
            GC.Collect()
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        Else
            isfound = False
        End If
    Next

    ' Add new calls
    isfound = False
    For Each tmp In newCoreCalls
        For Each tmp3 As objCoreCall In qcalls.Controls
            If tmp.CallID = tmp3.CallID Then
                isfound = True
            End If
        Next
        If isfound = False Then
            qcalls.Controls.Add(tmp)
            If InStr(UCase(tmp.Queue), "PARK") Then
            Else
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Insert from Added records: " & tmp.Queue)
                My.Computer.Audio.Play(Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath & "\priCall.wav", AudioPlayMode.Background)
            End If

        End If
        isfound = False
    Next
    For Each tmp2 In qcalls.Controls
        If InStr(UCase(tmp2.Queue), "PARK") Then
            tmp2.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Coral
        End If
    Next
    myreader.Close()
    newCoreCalls = Nothing
    a = Nothing
    myreader = Nothing
    tmp2 = Nothing
    tmp = Nothing

    Label1.Text = "Queue Core Calls (" & qcalls.Controls.Count & ")"
    tmrCoreCalls.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

I would appreciate any help and insight on this.  When this is running if there are any controls visible, the memory usage just keeps increasing.  Adding multiple controls increases the memory usage exponentially.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Anything which implements IDisposable (has a Dispose method) should be used in a `Using` block.  Setting it to Nothing is not the same thing,  `a` for instance looks like DBCommand object - it is never disposed, neither is the reader.  And since that is a timer event, well...quintuple the problem.  You can also run CodeAnalyzer on the project and it will tell you plenty of things about it.  You can also look at the USER and GDI objects in TaskManager to get an idea of what kind of resources you are leaking.

Comment: Ditto for any resources those UCs allocate.  Also creating controls is expensive.  Rather than adding new ones then removing dead ones, see if you can refactor it to work the other way: find dead ones and re-purpose them for the new query data.  Then just remove any extras so that you minimize both controls creation and removal/disposal.  And dont call GC in a loop - if at all.